# Why can't I one-hot encode my labels with TensorFlow? (Bad slice index None of type <type 'NoneType'>)

Tags: python, csv, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a CSV input pipeline into a TensorFlow model, and as part of that pipeline, I want to one-hot encode my labels.

Here's the code for my full model:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import math as math
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('dataset')
args = parser.parse_args()

# hyperparameters
num_labels = 2

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

def read_from_csv(filename_queue):
  reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
  _, csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)
  record_defaults = [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
  col1,col2,col3,col4,colLabel = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=record_defaults)
  features = tf.pack([col1,col2,col3,col4])  
  label = tf.pack([colLabel])  
  return features, label

def read_batches(batch_size, num_epochs=None):
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([args.dataset], num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)  
  example, label = read_from_csv(filename_queue)
  min_after_dequeue = 10000
  capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
  example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      [example, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
      min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
  return example_batch, label_batch

def reformat(dataset, labels):  
  dataset = tf.to_float(dataset)
  labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1])
  # labels = (np.arange(num_labels) == labels[:,None]).astype(np.float32)
  return dataset, labels

def input_pipeline(batch_size, num_epochs=None):
  example_batch, label_batch = read_batches(batch_size, num_epochs)
  train_dataset, train_labels = reformat(example_batch, label_batch)
  return train_dataset, train_labels

file_length = file_len(args.dataset) - 1
training_dataset, training_labels = input_pipeline(file_length, 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

  # start populating filename queue
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  try:
    while not coord.should_stop():
      training_dataset_batch, training_labels_batch = sess.run([training_dataset, training_labels]) 
      print("\nlabels:")
      print(training_labels_batch)
      print("\nlabels type:")
      print(type(training_labels_batch))
      print("\nlabels shape:")
      print(training_labels_batch.shape)
      print("\nlabels rank:")
      print(tf.rank(training_labels_batch))
  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('\nDone training, epoch reached')
  finally:
    coord.request_stop()

  coord.join(threads)
```

And here's some example CSV that will work with this model:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,label
0,0,0,0,0
0,15,0,0,0
0,30,0,0,1
0,45,0,0,1
1,0,0,0,2
1,15,0,0,2
1,30,0,0,3
1,45,0,0,3
```

If I run this code as-is, this is the output I get - at this point, I haven't enabled any one-hot encoding, and what you see here more or less makes sense - my array of labels has a shape of (8,) since there are 8 examples, and a rank of 0:

```
$ python model.py csv_test_data.csv 

labels:
[0 2 2 0 3 3 1 1]

labels type:
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

labels shape:
(8,)

labels rank:
Tensor("Rank:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)

Done training, epoch reached
(tensorflow)
```

The problem comes when I enable this line of code to one-hot encode the labels in `reformat`:

```
labels = (np.arange(num_labels) == labels[:,None]).astype(np.float32)
```

As soon as I introduce that, boom - it blows up on me:

```
$ python model.py csv_test_data.csv 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 51, in <module>
    training_dataset, training_labels = input_pipeline(file_length, 1)
  File "model.py", line 47, in input_pipeline
    train_dataset, train_labels = reformat(example_batch, label_batch)
  File "model.py", line 42, in reformat
    labels = (np.arange(num_labels) == labels[:,None]).astype(np.float32)
  File "/Users/rringham/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 161, in _SliceHelper
    raise TypeError("Bad slice index %s of type %s" % (s, type(s)))
TypeError: Bad slice index None of type <type 'NoneType'>
```

I'm really unclear as to why; I've used this same technique in other TensorFlow models, and it's worked just fine with almost identical label types - an array of values, a shape of (#,) where # is # of examples, and a rank of 0 - e.g.:
[image: working one-hot encoding example]

Is there anything obvious I'm missing here about why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be (another) incompatibility between NumPy slice syntax, and TensorFlow slice syntax. In NumPy, `labels[:, None]` is shorthand for adding a new dimension to the returned array, to turn a vector of length `N` into a matrix of size `N x 1`. TensorFlow doesn't understand this (currently), so you have use the [`tf.expand_dims()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#expand_dims) op instead:

```
tf.expand_dims(labels, 1)  # equivalent to `labels[:, None]` in NumPy.
```

However, once you fix this, you may run into other issues:

```
labels = (np.arange(num_labels) == labels[:,None]).astype(np.float32)
```

Since `labels` is a TensorFlow tensor and not a NumPy array, you won't be able to use NumPy methods, like the `==` operator and `astype()` on it. Here's how you would write this line using TensorFlow operators:

```
labels = tf.cast(
    tf.equal(tf.range(num_labels), tf.expand_dims(labels, 1)), tf.float32)
```

**PS.** The new [`tf.one_hot()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#one_hot) op might be an easier way to convert your data to a one-hot encoding.

Comment: Both options ended up working great (both tf.expand_dims() and tf.one_hot())